# cannot find symbol on .readObject();

Tags: java, serialization

I'm having trouble loading my save file and its showing me a "cannot find symbol" error in the .readObject() of the 2 int variables. I properly declared the variables and both variables are global. I have no idea why. I tried searching for an answer so i end up here. ty in advance guys

```
public void loadGame()
{
    //Load Game
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream saveFile = new FileOutputStream("save.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream load = new ObjectOutputStream(saveFile);
        cursortrigger = (Integer) load.readObject();
        soundtrigger = (Integer) load.readObject();
        load.close();   
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public void saveGame()
{
    //Save Game
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream saveFile = new FileOutputStream("save.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream save = new ObjectOutputStream(saveFile);
        save.writeObject(cursortrigger);
        save.writeObject(soundtrigger);
        save.close();   
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
FileOutputStream saveFile = new FileOutputStream("save.txt");
ObjectOutputStream load = new ObjectOutputStream(saveFile);
```

This is wrong. To ***read*** objects, you need `ObjectInputStream` and `FileInputStream`.

```
FileInputStream saveFile = new FileInputStream("save.txt");
ObjectInputStream load = new ObjectInputStream(saveFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need ObjectInputStream, not ObjectOutputStream. Also FileInputStream.